# How to get the trackball tooltip on top centre of trackball line using SfCartesianChart in flutter

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

Unable to get the tooltip in the top centre of a trackball line when using SfCartesianChart in flutter.

I have tried the following code:

```
class InvestmentCalculator extends StatefulWidget {
  const InvestmentCalculator({super.key});

  @override
  State<InvestmentCalculator> createState() => _InvestmentCalculatorState();
}

class _InvestmentCalculatorState extends State<InvestmentCalculator> {
  late TrackballBehavior _trackballBehavior;

  List<ChartData> chartData = [];

  List<int> timeStamps = [
    1689859800,
    1689859860,
    1689859920,
    1689859980,
    1689860040,
    1689860100,
    1689860160,
    1689860220,
    1689860280,
    1689860340,
    1689860400,
    1689860460,
    1689860520,
    1689860580,
    1689860640,
    1689860700,
    1689860760,
    1689860820,
    1689860880,
    1689860940,
    1689861000,
    1689861060,
    1689861120,
    1689861180,
    1689861240,
    1689861300,
    1689861360,
    1689861420,
    1689861480,
    1689861540,
    1689861600,
    1689861660,
    1689861720,
    1689861780,
    1689861840,
    1689861900,
    1689861960,
    1689862020,
    1689862080,
    1689862140,
    1689862200,
    1689862260,
    1689862320,
    1689862380,
    1689862440,
    1689862500,
    1689862560,
    1689862620,
    1689862680,
    1689862740,
    1689862800,
    1689862860,
    1689862920,
    1689862980,
    1689863040,
    1689863100,
    1689863160,
    1689863220,
    1689863280,
    1689863340,
    1689863400,
    1689863460,
    1689863520,
    1689863580,
    1689863640,
    1689863700,
    1689863760,
    1689863820,
    1689863880,
    1689863940,
    1689864000,
    1689864060,
    1689864120,
    1689864180,
    1689864240,
    1689864300,
    1689864360,
    1689864420,
    1689864480,
    1689864540,
    1689864600,
    1689864660,
    1689864720,
    1689864780,
    1689864840,
    1689864900,
    1689864960,
    1689865020,
    1689865080,
    1689865140,
    1689865200,
    1689865260,
    1689865320,
    1689865380,
    1689865440,
    1689865500,
    1689865560,
    1689865620,
    1689865680,
    1689865740,
    1689865800,
    1689865860,
    1689865920,
    1689865980,
    1689866040,
    1689866100,
    1689866160,
    1689866220,
    1689866280,
    1689866340,
    1689866400,
    1689866460,
    1689866520,
    1689866580,
    1689866640,
    1689866700,
    1689866760,
    1689866820,
    1689866880,
    1689866940,
    1689867000,
    1689867060,
    1689867120,
    1689867180,
    1689867240,
    1689867300,
    1689867360,
    1689867420,
    1689867480,
    1689867540,
    1689867600,
    1689867660,
    1689867720,
    1689867780,
    1689867840,
    1689867900,
    1689867960,
    1689868020,
    1689868080,
    1689868140,
    1689868200,
    1689868260,
    1689868320,
    1689868380,
    1689868440,
    1689868500,
    1689868560,
    1689868620,
    1689868680,
    1689868740,
    1689868800,
    1689868860,
    1689868920,
    1689868980,
    1689869040,
    1689869100,
    1689869160,
    1689869220,
    1689869280,
    1689869340,
    1689869400,
    1689869460,
    1689869520,
    1689869580,
    1689869640,
    1689869700,
    1689869760,
    1689869820,
    1689869880,
    1689869940,
    1689870000,
    1689870060,
    1689870120,
    1689870180,
    1689870240,
    1689870300,
    1689870360,
    1689870420,
    1689870480,
    1689870540,
    1689870600,
    1689870660,
    1689870720,
    1689870780,
    1689870840,
    1689870900,
    1689870960,
    1689871020,
    1689871080,
    1689871140,
    1689871200,
    1689871260,
    1689871320,
    1689871380,
    1689871440,
    1689871500,
    1689871560,
    1689871620,
    1689871680,
    1689871740,
    1689871800,
    1689871860,
    1689871920,
    1689871980,
    1689872040,
    1689872100,
    1689872160,
    1689872220,
    1689872280,
    1689872340,
    1689872400,
    1689872460,
    1689872520,
    1689872580,
    1689872640,
    1689872700,
    1689872760,
    1689872820,
    1689872880,
    1689872940,
    1689873000,
    1689873060,
    1689873120,
    1689873180,
    1689873240,
    1689873300,
    1689873360,
    1689873420,
    1689873480,
    1689873540,
    1689873600,
    1689873660,
    1689873720,
    1689873780,
    1689873840,
    1689873900,
    1689873960,
    1689874020,
    1689874080,
    1689874140,
    1689874200,
    1689874260,
    1689874320,
    1689874380,
    1689874440,
    1689874500,
    1689874560,
    1689874620,
    1689874680,
    1689874740,
    1689874800,
    1689874860,
    1689874920,
    1689874980,
    1689875040,
    1689875100,
    1689875160,
    1689875220,
    1689875280,
    1689875340,
    1689875400,
    1689875460,
    1689875520,
    1689875580,
    1689875640,
    1689875700,
    1689875760,
    1689875820,
    1689875880,
    1689875940,
    1689876000,
    1689876060,
    1689876120,
    1689876180,
    1689876240,
    1689876300,
    1689876360,
    1689876420,
    1689876480,
    1689876540,
    1689876600,
    1689876660,
    1689876720,
    1689876780,
    1689876840,
    1689876900,
    1689876960,
    1689877020,
    1689877080,
    1689877140,
    1689877200,
    1689877260,
    1689877320,
    1689877380,
    1689877440,
    1689877500,
    1689877560,
    1689877620,
    1689877680,
    1689877740,
    1689877800,
    1689877860,
    1689877920,
    1689877980,
    1689878040,
    1689878100,
    1689878160,
    1689878220,
    1689878280,
    1689878340,
    1689878400,
    1689878460,
    1689878520,
    1689878580,
    1689878640,
    1689878700,
    1689878760,
    1689878820,
    1689878880,
    1689878940,
    1689879000,
    1689879060,
    1689879120,
    1689879180,
    1689879240,
    1689879300,
    1689879360,
    1689879420,
    1689879480,
    1689879540,
    1689879600,
    1689879660,
    1689879720,
    1689879780,
    1689879840,
    1689879900,
    1689879960,
    1689880020,
    1689880080,
    1689880140,
    1689880200,
    1689880260,
    1689880320,
    1689880380,
    1689880440,
    1689880500,
    1689880560,
    1689880620,
    1689880680,
    1689880740,
    1689880800,
    1689880860,
    1689880920,
    1689880980,
    1689881040,
    1689881100,
    1689881160,
    1689881220,
    1689881280,
    1689881340,
    1689881400,
    1689881460,
    1689881520,
    1689881580,
    1689881640,
    1689881700,
    1689881760,
    1689881820,
    1689881880,
    1689881940,
    1689882000,
    1689882060,
    1689882120,
    1689882180,
    1689882240,
    1689882300,
    1689882360,
    1689882420,
    1689882480,
    1689882540,
    1689882600,
    1689882660,
    1689882720,
    1689882780,
    1689882840,
    1689882900,
    1689882960,
    1689883020,
    1689883080,
    1689883140,
    1689883200
  ];

  List<double> values = [
    3127.20611273658,
    3125.99451243038,
    3126.57173497738,
    3126.75095341143,
    3127.32572636153,
    3126.51514818151,
    3125.37572392071,
    3124.65305438164,
    3125.77450283016,
    3125.68866246275,
    3125.10420584883,
    3124.94882071889,
    3126.61819960581,
    3126.86430754705,
    3125.27315049369,
    3125.89925096342,
    3126.38872061847,
    3127.00847261262,
    3128.03482221896,
    3127.69612175144,
    3127.94835683811,
    3127.56752581312,
    3127.78246571898,
    3128.21902436174,
    3128.88671705105,
    3128.68502217412,
    3127.9338668803,
    3127.72231089941,
    3127.72352586807,
    3127.49617246953,
    3128.39980241404,
    3127.44000857893,
    3127.0783953957,
    3127.7836440102,
    3126.69153800087,
    3126.00391721234,
    3125.73036984393,
    3124.96872380558,
    3123.97633925522,
    3124.62415521032,
    3123.02086588038,
    3122.18045967058,
    3123.26757206115,
    3124.40198964134,
    3122.86479917198,
    3122.15462812075,
    3122.19086134144,
    3121.98230541589,
    3121.006467669,
    3120.70273709547,
    3120.84789846242,
    3119.97805686878,
    3120.35693693089,
    3120.16778091333,
    3119.16275367726,
    3119.31774918007,
    3118.50983613093,
    3117.54910083173,
    3117.42436698341,
    3117.8112031558,
    3118.28065612827,
    3117.99618298913,
    3117.34909196431,
    3117.22530771482,
    3116.48725387961,
    3115.79833448578,
    3116.16500013657,
    3117.27350951471,
    3116.06863829744,
    3115.91091396008,
    3114.66396602926,
    3115.77031431387,
    3115.67905297059,
    3115.05127623105,
    3114.54204267081,
    3114.89377580711,
    3115.8821647341,
    3116.9249936663,
    3116.08782322958,
    3116.38071636174,
    3116.63669526763,
    3116.86204886559,
    3117.63797444523,
    3117.88941044963,
    3118.0010175398,
    3117.95066424036,
    3117.91232195891,
    3117.59780383465,
    3117.91323215752,
    3118.85177896285,
    3118.6820397181,
    3118.83693634226,
    3119.23024818723,
    3119.12008597967,
    3119.27686538066,
    3119.83643205673,
    3119.28070287956,
    3119.78536908351,
    3119.64958779883,
    3119.02869031154,
    3119.20776842021,
    3120.1100862441,
    3119.97251091458,
    3119.50454470266,
    3119.45165494475,
    3118.74773751325,
    3119.31796122549,
    3118.65789307056,
    3118.7615757694,
    3118.23806253157,
    3118.17589699779,
    3118.38315432988,
    3117.55460263715,
    3117.49608800988,
    3117.52821752319,
    3117.82062506476,
    3117.81225994097,
    3118.23337715073,
    3118.67626988316,
    3117.98137430784,
    3117.76760445428,
    3117.75496176857,
    3118.37583514482,
    3118.66322585912,
    3118.04057282394,
    3118.36635547546,
    3118.94822509846,
    3118.99407112486,
    3119.5190706877,
    3119.89499981205,
    3119.62949920904,
    3119.02940185198,
    3119.40426978927,
    3119.32394609007,
    3119.48522351254,
    3118.95134370837,
    3118.73543837873,
    3117.87668358899,
    3117.32814399743,
    3117.48233736722,
    3117.17773342387,
    3117.50831289657,
    3117.69343975576,
    3118.67295432432,
    3118.75500098187,
    3117.90423229467,
    3118.42845093509,
    3118.86301420244,
    3119.00644837179,
    3118.98076149989,
    3118.79710607597,
    3119.42329598613,
    3118.92130191615,
    3119.75265249173,
    3119.78972634239,
    3120.09527522211,
    3119.57441925228,
    3119.52562730043,
    3119.93229105142,
    3120.31595993627,
    3121.06574201933,
    3120.6633219285,
    3120.94486776735,
    3121.10621174574,
    3120.87553432387,
    3120.62213840452,
    3120.77093457147,
    3121.14569271648,
    3120.98954204744,
    3120.16425343821,
    3119.71512453504,
    3119.07627158732,
    3119.12536535768,
    3118.49836907525,
    3118.09992928667,
    3117.78983836421,
    3118.17169709162,
    3118.40834356713,
    3118.88193075901,
    3119.11924789935,
    3118.72029507242,
    3118.08472931924,
    3118.86142987011,
    3118.86925405873,
    3118.34450417633,
    3117.36267569989,
    3117.93552651746,
    3117.32839647273,
    3116.05594980684,
    3116.58210125029,
    3116.21939060221,
    3117.12617341641,
    3117.18575291899,
    3117.81428932657,
    3117.25804972458,
    3117.12644172201,
    3116.96780718604,
    3117.40267984955,
    3117.59922510696,
    3117.5149053125,
    3118.19408385922,
    3118.40494339568,
    3118.38043675468,
    3118.34046395402,
    3118.24150683956,
    3118.36013598533,
    3117.72225632427,
    3117.67780761967,
    3117.55983899207,
    3117.46111128924,
    3117.55810000416,
    3117.28278513708,
    3118.08433359804,
    3117.5883340168,
    3117.60380017646,
    3118.00459070171,
    3117.99145665356,
    3118.40023465819,
    3118.31072462355,
    3117.89382906003,
    3117.02401627015,
    3117.25056753567,
    3117.81774054249,
    3117.96458150122,
    3117.97102156545,
    3117.76408429185,
    3117.25623686792,
    3117.25549582504,
    3116.58772765968,
    3116.17800047943,
    3116.24089735106,
    3116.77806858902,
    3117.30700617138,
    3116.50770625256,
    3116.67586839306,
    3116.21922474779,
    3116.38678746026,
    3117.0611457832,
    3117.68928665624,
    3117.92874640051,
    3117.99971971838,
    3118.2325029093,
    3118.19622859438,
    3118.59190346649,
    3118.90137884832,
    3118.84099297347,
    3118.94289601338,
    3118.61423781446,
    3118.21410780738,
    3117.66261500037,
    3117.22451821244,
    3117.63148518904,
    3117.83889258422,
    3117.72621637949,
    3118.05244836569,
    3118.45967895517,
    3118.90012347938,
    3118.87996432488,
    3118.9628600909,
    3118.92953005946,
    3119.1671367782,
    3119.34724258929,
    3119.53709810203,
    3118.9911271111,
    3118.20364324875,
    3118.00709799134,
    3117.91807931914,
    3118.21593242768,
    3118.23809257126,
    3118.12808166565,
    3117.69889058683,
    3117.08200315918,
    3117.42638143745,
    3117.59804195598,
    3117.37933655499,
    3117.59394414992,
    3117.4020876481,
    3117.91864615763,
    3118.05300341387,
    3118.53357249416,
    3118.02788036165,
    3117.40383895674,
    3117.25797857467,
    3117.01491238678,
    3117.1105750167,
    3116.80123014943,
    3116.06376559559,
    3116.16169924688,
    3116.26100610893,
    3115.87063595016,
    3115.22883826549,
    3114.72482408111,
    3115.35860593611,
    3115.60007090871,
    3115.83166491666,
    3115.15023875117,
    3114.13325769785,
    3113.44678573918,
    3113.50349903161,
    3112.74822182069,
    3111.87571702505,
    3113.58825846756,
    3114.18734555886,
    3114.00416069206,
    3113.78310879365,
    3113.92456364983,
    3114.29372755346,
    3114.50172087977,
    3114.98555302514,
    3115.18679127739,
    3115.29711793395,
    3114.94042636571,
    3115.38963498418,
    3114.84776770063,
    3114.48130899408,
    3114.86617978574,
    3115.31730967799,
    3115.60321911594,
    3115.61126463471,
    3115.47571058759,
    3115.23946256181,
    3115.83842926679,
    3115.81626912321,
    3115.42369832112,
    3115.5588377268,
    3115.84129430077,
    3115.08392027287,
    3115.06235955732,
    3115.77319230289,
    3114.54482427484,
    3114.51252436085,
    3114.98110743746,
    3114.59312788306,
    3114.31228529858,
    3114.54976996893,
    3113.80291213541,
    3113.70570209034,
    3113.97904855788,
    3113.84126628412,
    3113.94575111598,
    3113.68881998372,
    3113.8518325047,
    3114.13949325129,
    3114.60116525308,
    3113.79721602925,
    3113.72391319715,
    3112.80340114602,
    3112.40221508623,
    3112.30803876339,
    3112.22351343179,
    3112.31119163308,
    3112.21260170287,
    3112.59320048408,
    3111.91100053586,
    3111.70226192742,
    3111.77402039512,
    3111.29334111944,
    3110.97942242321,
    3111.33391334813,
    3110.73457657639,
    3111.10558242368,
    3112.37119941005,
    3113.08908863107,
    3112.87465100128,
    3112.85106259001,
    3112.41308071029,
    3112.91357363213,
    3112.61102752875,
    3113.00809167144,
    3112.93398670632,
    3113.02744869292,
    3113.8350082026,
    3114.08017544672,
    3113.97526539122,
    3113.72500066565,
    3113.66361225058,
    3113.32495161882,
    3113.59514521667,
    3112.98355442088,
    3113.21620024229,
    3113.13251429571,
    3113.84174158674,
    3114.14379632768,
    3114.44825020794,
    3114.87623937995,
    3113.93819485069,
    3114.48380714196,
    3114.17670660784,
    3114.28623418213,
    3114.26222780528,
    3114.64218516096
  ];

  var formats;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    formats = NumberFormat("#,##0", "en_US");
    _trackballBehavior = TrackballBehavior(
        enable: true,
        markerSettings: const TrackballMarkerSettings(
            height: 10,
            width: 10,
            // markerVisibility: TrackballVisibilityMode.visible,
            borderColor: Colors.black,
            borderWidth: 4,
            color: Colors.blue),
        activationMode: ActivationMode.singleTap,
        shouldAlwaysShow: true,
        builder: (context, trackballDetails) {
          return Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: (4), right: (4), top: (2)),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
            width: (65),
            height: (40),
            // height: 200,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "${trackballDetails.groupingModeInfo!.points[0].x}",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 8),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 2,
                ),
                Text(
                  "AED ${formats.format(trackballDetails.groupingModeInfo!.points[0].y)}",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    fontSize: 8,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        tooltipDisplayMode: TrackballDisplayMode.groupAllPoints,
        tooltipAlignment: ChartAlignment.near);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    chartData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < timeStamps.length; i++) {
      DateTime dt = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeStamps[i] * 1000,
          isUtc: true);
      // String datetime = DateFormat.MMMd().format(dt);
      chartData.add(ChartData(x: dt, y: values[i]));
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: SfCartesianChart(
            trackballBehavior: _trackballBehavior,
            primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
                dateFormat: DateFormat.Hms(),
                intervalType: DateTimeIntervalType.minutes,
                interval: 1,
                majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0),
                majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(width: 0)),
            primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0),
                majorTickLines: MajorTickLines(width: 0)),
            series: <ChartSeries>[
              // Renders fast line chart
              AreaSeries<ChartData, DateTime>(
                  dataSource: chartData,
                  xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
                  yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChartData {
  DateTime? x;
  double? y;
  ChartData({
    @required this.x,
    @required this.y,
  });
}
```

and it results in the following:
my graph : -

[image]

but i want it to be like this
expected graph : -

[image]

Does any one know if it is achievable using SfCartesianChart in flutter and how should i go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In [SfCartesianChart](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/SfCartesianChart-class.html), there is no direct support for rendering the trackball tooltip on the top center of the trackball line. The current behavior is that the trackball tooltip will only render on the left or right side of the trackball line. However, you can use the CustomPaint widget and [TooltipBehavior.showByIndex](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/TooltipBehavior/showByIndex.html) method to render the tooltip at the top center of the trackball line. I have shared a code snippet below for your reference.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Chart Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

double? xPos;
double? yPos;
double? xPosEnd;
double? yPosEnd;

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ValueNotifier<int> customTrackballRepaintNotifier = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  late ChartSeriesController _chartSeriesController;
  late TooltipBehavior _tooltipBehavior;
  late Timer timer;
  late List<ChartData> chartData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    chartData = [
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 20), 12),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 21), 15),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 22), 12),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 23), 15),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 24), 12),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 25), 11),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 26), 15),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 27), 13),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 28), 14),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 29), 14),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 30), 14),
      ChartData(DateTime(2023, 01, 01, 08, 31), 14),
    ];
    _tooltipBehavior = TooltipBehavior(
      enable: true,
      opacity: 0,
      activationMode: ActivationMode.none,
      shouldAlwaysShow: true,
      builder: (data, point, series, pointIndex, seriesIndex) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 70,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                DateFormat.jm().format(point.x),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      // Modify the data point as per your requirement
      ChartData data = chartData[8];
      Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
        Offset position = _chartSeriesController.pointToPixel(
            CartesianChartPoint(
                (data.x as DateTime).millisecondsSinceEpoch, data.y));
        Offset positionEnd = _chartSeriesController.pointToPixel(
            CartesianChartPoint(
                (data.x as DateTime).millisecondsSinceEpoch, 0));
        xPos = position.dx;
        yPos = position.dy;
        xPosEnd = positionEnd.dx;
        yPosEnd = positionEnd.dy;
        customTrackballRepaintNotifier.value++;
        _tooltipBehavior.show(data.x, data.y);
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter chart'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SfCartesianChart(
                      tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
                        majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
                      ),
                      primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                        minimum: 0,
                        majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
                      ),
                      series: <CartesianSeries>[
                        SplineAreaSeries<ChartData, DateTime>(
                          dataSource: chartData,
                          onPointTap: (details) {
                            Offset position = _chartSeriesController.pointToPixel(
                                CartesianChartPoint(
                                    (details.dataPoints![details.pointIndex!].x
                                            as DateTime)
                                        .millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                                    details.dataPoints![details.pointIndex!].y));
                            Offset positionEnd = _chartSeriesController
                                .pointToPixel(CartesianChartPoint(
                                    (details.dataPoints![details.pointIndex!].x
                                            as DateTime)
                                        .millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                                    0));
                            xPos = position.dx;
                            yPos = position.dy;
                            xPosEnd = positionEnd.dx;
                            yPosEnd = positionEnd.dy;
                            customTrackballRepaintNotifier.value++;
                            _tooltipBehavior.showByIndex(
                                details.seriesIndex!, details.pointIndex!);
                          },
                          onRendererCreated: (controller) {
                            _chartSeriesController = controller;
                          },
                          xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
                          yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y,
                          borderWidth: 4,
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          borderGradient: const LinearGradient(
                            colors: <Color>[
                              Colors.yellow,
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 220, 7),
                            ],
                            stops: <double>[
                              0.4,
                              0.9,
                            ],
                            begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            end: Alignment.topCenter,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    CustomPaint(
                      painter: DrawCircle(
                        notifier: customTrackballRepaintNotifier,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawCircle extends CustomPainter {
  DrawCircle({required ValueNotifier<num> notifier}) : super(repaint: notifier);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (xPos != null && yPos != null) {
      const double chartPadding = 10;
      final double centerX = xPos! + chartPadding;
      final double centerY = yPos! + chartPadding;
      final double centerEndX = xPosEnd! + chartPadding;
      final double centerEndY = yPosEnd! + chartPadding;
      const double radius = 10;
      canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(centerX, centerY),
        radius,
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.yellow
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill,
      );
      canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(centerX, centerY),
        radius,
        Paint()
          ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(1)
          ..strokeWidth = 4.0
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..isAntiAlias = true,
      );
      canvas.drawLine(
        Offset(centerX, centerY),
        Offset(centerEndX, centerEndY),
        Paint()
          ..shader = ui.Gradient.linear(
            Offset(centerX, centerY),
            Offset(centerEndX, centerEndY),
            <Color>[
              Colors.yellow,
              Colors.black,
            ],
            <double>[
              0.4,
              0.9,
            ],
          )
          ..strokeWidth = 2.0
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawCircle oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class ChartData {
  ChartData(this.x, this.y);
  final DateTime x;
  final double y;
}
```